# App Crashed: After installing in Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

Please I need someone to help with this problem. After running and installing the app, on clicking the app icon on emulator, the below error was prompted which I have no idea what was wrong. I am using Scringo SDK as a library.

```
      11-18 07:10:23.512: W/dalvikvm(918): Unable to resolve superclass of           Lcom/iueamessenger/MainActivity  (1010)
      11-18 07:10:23.543: W/dalvikvm(918): Link of class 'Lcom/iueamessenger/MainActivity;' failed
      11-18 07:10:23.553: D/AndroidRuntime(918): Shutting down VM
      11-18 07:10:23.572: W/dalvikvm(918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception           (group=0x40a71930)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to           instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.iueamessenger/com.iueamessenger.MainActivity}:           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.iueamessenger.MainActivity" on path:           /data/app/com.iueamessenger-1.apk
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at           android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at           android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.iueamessenger.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.iueamessenger-1.apk
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
      11-18 07:10:23.603: E/AndroidRuntime(918):    ... 11 more
      11-18 07:10:30.733: I/Process(918): Sending signal. PID: 918 SIG: 9
```

Below is the MainActivity.java class:

```
package com.iueamessenger;

import com.scringo.Scringo;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Scringo scringo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Scringo.setAppId("2LvLgedRxUvdu2prC83qfjmIYzA8by2c");
        scringo = new Scringo(this);
        scringo.init();
        scringo.addSidebar();
        Scringo.setDebugMode(true);
        }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        scringo.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        scringo.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The Android Manifest XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iueamessenger"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try to change the main activity name in manifest to "com.iueamessenger.MainActivity"

Comment: `Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/iueamessenger/MainActivity` so try to check if the support library which holds `ActionBarActivity` is part of your APK. Maybe the code is obfuscated by ProGuard

Answer (score 0):

The error showing that the app did not found MainActivity, try to write the ActivityName with full package name in Android.Manifest
like **@Opiatefuchs** said in the comment.
Declare activity-name not as **MainActivity** but as **"com.iueamessenger.MainActivity"**

Answer (score 0):

Your project seems to b ok.
**Clean** your Project and **restart your SDK**.
It do the magic some times.

If problem still exist you can create a new project and copy every thing of it to the new one.